# swagger springfox - bean validation JSR 303 not recognize

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

I followed this tutorial https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-restful-api-documentation-with-swagger-2/ to generate a swagger documentation.
It's working but when I try to add some validation in my bean I don't find the information in the documentation:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Creates a product",
        notes="Populates a product instance bla bla")
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity saveProduct(  @Valid @RequestBody Product product){
    productService.saveProduct(product);
    return new ResponseEntity("Product saved successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

My entity with the validations annotations :

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   // @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The database generated product ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Version
   // @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The auto-generated version of the product")
    @NotNull
    private Integer version;
   // @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The application-specific product ID" )
    private String productId;
   // @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The product description")
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String description;
   // @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The image URL of the product")
    private String imageUrl;
   // @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The price of the product", required = true)
    @NotNull
    private BigDecimal price;
```

But when I check the documentation I don't have those validation information:

[image]

Here https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/987 they say that we need to update our dependencies and it's what I did :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Did I miss something in the configuration? Any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution in this post : http://vojtechruzicka.com/documenting-spring-boot-rest-api-swagger-springfox/. 
All is explained :

Unfortunately, JSR-303 based documentation does not work out of the box, you need an additional dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And you need to import BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration configuration file on top of your swagger configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
public class SpringFoxConfig {
  ...
}
```

Thank you @vojtech-ruzicka https://stackoverflow.com/users/4560142/vojtech-ruzicka

Comment: Just to clarify, it works out of the box. It is just that it is optional. Not all projects use jsr 303 and bean validation. It has been documented [here](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-support-for-jsr-303).

Comment: It seems that it does not recognize Hibernate specific annotations like @NotBlunk(only standard, JSR 303, @NotNull) , do you know how to solve that problem too?

Comment: @DilipKrishnan could you please comment on this?

Comment: It doesnt implement all the annotations, just `@NotNull`, `@Size` and a few others. However the plugin extensibility model lets you define your own plugins to achieve the same.